# Can't define two relationships between the same two entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I can't get EF 6 Code First to map the following two relationships the way I want them.

There are two entities: `Template` and `TemplateVersion`.

Every `TemplateVersion` has exactly one `ParentTemplate`.

A `Template` has a collection of `TemplateVersion`s.

This was the first, simple, 1:many relationship, with navigation properties on both sides.

Now for the second:

From all `TemplateVersion`s associated to a `Template`, only one (e.g. the "newest") is the `CurrentTemplateVersion` for that `Template`.

So: `Template` has a navigation property `CurrentVersion`, and an associated property `CurrentVersionId`.
There is no corresponding navigation property on the `TemplateVersion` side.

So, I would say, this second `Template : TemplateVersion` relation is `0..1 : 1`.

Here are the models:

```
public class Template
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [...]
    public virtual int CurrentVersionId { get; set; }
    public virtual TemplateVersion CurrentVersion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TemplateVersion> Versions { get; set; }
}

public class TemplateVersion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [...]
    public virtual int ParentTemplateId { get; set; }
    public virtual Template ParentTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

I like to keep my model classes free from DB specifics, so I defined the relationships in the context:

```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
            .HasMany(template => template.Versions)
            .WithRequired(version => version.ParentTemplate)
            ;

        modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
            .HasRequired(template => template.CurrentVersion)
            .WithOptional()
            ;
   }
```

The problem is, the 2nd relation doesn't work as expected.

Using EF Power Tools plugin, I reverse-engineer the model diagram. Here's what I get:

1st relation, 1:many (ok)

[image]

2nd relation, 0..1:1

Notice that `CurrentVersionId` property is *not* part of the relation, and `Template.Id` is !

[image]

The generated DB tables mirror exactly this: `CurrentVersionId` is not part of any foreign key, and `Id` on the `Template` table incorrectly is defined as a foreign key to `Id` on the `TemplateVersion` table.

What am I missing ?

PS. Even if I remove the 1st relationship completely, the 2nd one is the same.

Answer (score 1):

In a one-to-one relationship, EF requires the PK of the dependent end also has to be the FK of the relationship:

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   //...
}
public class Boo
{
   [Key,ForeignKey("Foo")]
   public int FooId{get;set;}
   public virtual Foo Foo{get;set;}
   //...
}
```

If you need that `TemplateVersion` has its own `Id`, then, to resolve your issue you could configure that relationship this way:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
        .HasRequired(template => template.CurrentVersion)
        .WithMany().HasForeignKey(t=>t.CurrentVersionId);
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, although it doesn't intuitively look right to me to have that 2nd relation be many:1.

Comment: Exactly, it is a one-to-many relationship but I thought it could help to resolve your problem. If you want to maintain the one-to-one configuration, then don't declare the FK property and work only with the navigation properties, EF will handle the FK for you.